# Generic type parameter as method argument

Tags: java, generics, arguments

I have generic interface:

```
public interface StreamObserver<V>  {
    void onNext(V value);
}
```

And have to create objects for different types (`SubscribeTradesResponse` 
 and `SubscribeOrderResponse`):

1)

```
StreamObserver<SubscribeTradesResponse> getTradesResponseStream() {
    return new StreamObserver<SubscribeTradesResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(SubscribeTradesResponse response) {
            responseOnNextAction(response);
        }
    };
}
```

2)

```
StreamObserver<SubscribeOrderResponse> getOrderResponseStream() {
    return new StreamObserver<SubscribeOrderResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(SubscribeOrderResponse response) {
            responseOnNextAction(response);
        }
    };
}
```

Is it possible to make a common method `getResponseStream()` and pass `SubscribeTradesResponse` or `SubscribeOrderResponse` as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do even better by using lambda expressions, which will allow you to get rid of `getTradesResponseStream` and `getOrderResponseStream`:

```
StreamObserver<SubscribeTradesResponse>  tradeObserver= response -> 
      responseOnNextAction(response);
//or
StreamObserver<SubscribeTradesResponse>  tradeObserver= 
      this::responseOnNextAction;

StreamObserver<SubscribeOrderResponse> orderObserver = response -> 
      responseOnNextAction(response);
//or
StreamObserver<SubscribeOrderResponse> orderObserver = 
      this::responseOnNextAction;
```

That assumes you have overloaded `responseOnNextAction` accordingly.

But if you were to use the inner classes, you can still make the method generic:

```
<T> StreamObserver<T> getTradesResponseStream() {
    return new StreamObserver<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(T response) {
            responseOnNextAction(response);
        }
    };
}
```

But this depends on the signature of `responseOnNextAction`. It will work as is if the method takes an `Object`, but if it takes a `Response` of a sort, you may have to change the type parameter to 
`<T extends Response>`

Comment: Excelent! `<T> StreamObserver<T> getResponseStream()` does exact what I want. Thanks!. But how does it know what type `T` will be?

Comment: @suit Strictly speaking, it doesn't know. The type safety relies on the implementation of `responseOnNextAction(response)`. The generic method is facilitating the casting, but the return value of `responseOnNextAction` must still be compatible.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a common interface for the two response types:

```
interface TradeOrOrderResponse {
}
```

with

```
class SubscribeTradesResponse implements TradeOrOrderResponse
```

and

```
class SubscribeOrderResponse implements TradeOrOrderResponse
```

and then extend your observer-interface

```
public interface TOResponseObserver extends StreamObserver<V extends TradeOrOrderResponse>  {
    void onNext(V value);
}
```

and if your `responseOnNextAction` takes that interface

```
void responseOnNextAction(TradeOrOrderResponse resp)
```

it implements the `TOResponseObserver` interface, ie you can use it to handle either `SubscribeTradesResponse` or `SubscribeOrderResponse` objects.

Comment: I thought about `class SubscribeTradesResponse implements TradeOrOrderResponse`, unfortunately, this is an external library, i can't add `implements` to this class

Comment: @suit You could write a simple wrapper method in the interface for both classes... but then you'd probably face the same problem as you do now :/